# CSRF token missing or incorrect, even after including the token tag

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am getting a 'CSRF token missing or incorrect' error, but I have already added the `{% csrf_token%}` tag in the web form. Any idea why I still face this error?

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RequestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'index.html')
    else:
        form = RequestForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})`
```

I cannot post the template, but I use the token as shown in line below

```
<form id="reqForm" action="" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">{% csrf_token %}
```

Comment: If you view the source of your form can you see a hidden input box with csrf token values?

Comment: yeah now i can, after removing enctype attribute. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem is `enctype="text/plain"` in your form. The CSRF protection assumes that the post data is form encoded.

The simplest fix is to remove that entirely, which is equivalent to:

```
enctype="enctype=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

If you were uploading files in your form you would use:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: Yep, I am uploading a file in my web form, any idea how should I handle in backend? I am using models.FileField() in my model.

Comment: That's really a separate question. I would start with [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads) and ask a new question if you get stuck.