# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-csrf

i'm just starting to implement post request on my project but i have trouble with the csrf token.

Even if it seem i used it correctly (I use render, have cookie enable, {% csrf_token %} is in the html code and i have the middleware in django settings)

Edit :
Full view.py :

```
def mouvementCreation(request):
    idMI = 0
    especes = TbEspece.objects.order_by('id')
    #Get Mouvement informations

    #Connection to 'erp-site' DB 
    cursor = connections['erp-site'].cursor()
    try:
        #Get Produits list from Espece
        query = "{CALL SP_webGET_PRODUIT_FROM_ESPECE(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)}"
        arguments = (2016, 'C', 0, 10, 'A',)
        cursor.execute(query, arguments)
        produits = dictfetchall(cursor)

        #Get Transporters list
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_TRANSPORT}")
        transporters = dictfetchall(cursor)

        #Get Livreur list
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_LIVREUR}")
        livreurs = dictfetchall(cursor)
    finally:
        cursor.close()       

    cursor = connections['site'].cursor()
    try:
        #Get Circuit list
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_CIRCUIT_FOR_MVT}")
        circuits = dictfetchall(cursor)

        #Get Source list
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_SOURCE_FOR_MVT}")
        mvtsources = dictfetchall(cursor)

        #Get Dest list
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_DEST_FOR_MVT}")
        destinations = dictfetchall(cursor)

        #Get PontBascule list
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_PBASCULE}")
        pontBascules = dictfetchall(cursor)
    finally:
        cursor.close()

    reg_normes = TbRegauxnormes.objects.all()
    ordreexecs = TbOrdreexecution.objects.all()
    form = mouvementForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        pont = form.cleaned_data['pont']
        dateheure = form.cleaned_data['dateheure']
        poid = form.cleaned_data['poid']
        dsd = form.cleaned_data['dsd']
        typepesee = form.cleaned_data['typepesee']
        #Connection to 'erp-site' DB 
        cursor = connections['pontbascule'].cursor()
        try:
            #Get Produits list from Espece
            query = "{CALL SP_ADD_MANUAL_PESEE(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s,%s,%s)}"
            arguments = (pont, 'TICKETCHEAT', dateheure, poid, dsd,typepesee, '','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','')
            cursor.execute(query, arguments)
        finally:
            cursor.close()  
    return render(request, 'mouvementCreation.html', {'form': form, 'especes' : especes, 'produits' : produits, 'transporters' :  transporters, 'livreurs' : livreurs, 'circuits' : circuits, 'mvtsources' : mvtsources, 'destinations' : destinations, 'pontBascules' : pontBascules} )
```

template :

```
<form name="Form1" method="post" action="" enctype="text/plain" id="Form1">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" id="Editbox9" style="position:absolute;left:87px;top:46px;width:86px;height:16px;line-height:16px;z-index:173;" name="pont" value="" spellcheck="false">
<input type="text" id="Editbox34" style="position:absolute;left:87px;top:80px;width:86px;height:16px;line-height:16px;z-index:174;" name="dateheure" value="" spellcheck="false">
<input type="text" id="Editbox35" style="position:absolute;left:87px;top:114px;width:87px;height:16px;line-height:16px;z-index:175;" name="poid" value="" spellcheck="false">
<input type="text" id="Editbox36" style="position:absolute;left:88px;top:153px;width:84px;height:16px;line-height:16px;z-index:176;" name="dsd" value="" spellcheck="false">
<input type="text" id="Editbox37" style="position:absolute;left:87px;top:187px;width:86px;height:16px;line-height:16px;z-index:177;" name="typepesee" value="" spellcheck="false">
<input type="submit" id="Button14" name="submit" value="Submit" style="position:absolute;left:361px;top:65px;width:96px;height:25px;z-index:178;">
</form>
```

Middleware settings :

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

i have searched on multiple post and tried alot of fix but so far nothing worked and i'm still getting "Reason given for failure: CSRF token missing or incorrect."

Comment: Do you use the same view `mouvementCreation` to display the form and process the posted data? Does the token appear in the rendered html (view source in your browser to check)?.

Comment: The token does appear when i check the source in my browser yes. And yes, idealy what i want to do here is get the informations from the form in the view, and then call a stored procedure in my DB to create a new entry

Comment: Ah, I think the problem is `enctype="text/plain"`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526457/csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect-even-after-including-the-token-tag).

Comment: Yes that was the problem indeed, thanks alot man. I was also wondering, since as you can see in my view i'm calling a stored procedure after recieving the form, but the procedure never seem to trigger (The procedure work i tested it alone)

Comment: Sorry, that's a separate issue, so I can't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the request context to template.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: initially i thought this was the issue. But you are using render(). Render has inbuilt request context passed. This answer is not correct. Why are you passing locals() ? instead of locals, can you pass the form instance and other context as a dict ?

Comment: I'm using locals because that was used in the tutorial i was following on forms how do you pass the form instance ?

Comment: return render(request, 'mouvementCreation.html', {'form': form})

Comment: i tried but it doesn't seem to change much sadly

Comment: Can you paste your entire view ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your views.py

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(GetOrderCount, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: If i do i don't know how to make him able to resolve @method_decorator or GetOrderCount, Django doesn't seem to know thoses calls

Comment: Getordercounts should be the name of your class. And import from django.core.context_processors import csrf

Comment: it seem to work for the class part but the import isn't used, shouldn't it be (csrf) instead of (csrf_exempt) ?

Comment: I found the import to make it work but it doesn't resolve my csrf issue

Answer (score 0):

I temporarily fixed the problem, i had to comment "#'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',"
seem weird to have to do that in order for the csrf to work but at least it work.

Comment: This is not an ideal fix. By commenting out `CsrfViewMiddleware` you are disabling CSRF protection for your entire site.

Comment: I understand that, but at least i can work around it while i find a fix, do you have any idea what could cause that.